# Django url regex for username that accepts dots

Tags: regex, django, django-urls

I've been working with this url for username regex in Django for a while:

```
url(r'^.../(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$'
```

But now, I've got a strange case, sometimes Google answers with a username like this:

`luke.skywalker` *instead* of `lukeskywalker`

And it looks like my regex doesn't accept dots - I get a `NoReverseMatch`error. Could someone please help me with a correct regex?

Comment: Try: `[a-zA-Z.]+` and you may want to check the first answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid)

Comment: Note that google does the non-standard behavior that luke.skywalker@gmail.com and lukeskywalker@gmail.com are in fact the same email address.  Is your problem that you're not matching them (which Daniel Roseman's answer should handle and also get the dash/underscore/numbers that Gocht's comment answer won't], or that you also need to "normalize" things so that luke.skywalker and lukeskywalker get treated as the same username?  [I actually prefer the alternative such that I can create a relatively large # of test accounts from the same email address but I could see how normal might be annoyed]

Comment: @Foon Thanks for the info. I'm using Python Social Auth for the record (just in case someone finds this usefull).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can just add the characters you want to accept inside the square brackets:

```
r'^.../(?P<username>[-\w.]+)/$'
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply add `lookup_value_regex` to your ViewSet:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
      lookup_value_regex =  r"[\w.]+"
```

[Source](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#simplerouter)